# Why does SetCommState write three bytes to the serial?

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port

I am working with C++ and Arduino communication over serial.  I am able to write bytes, but I noticed that when I setup my `DCB` settings and use `SetCommState(m_hComm, &m_dcb)`, it writes three bytes, specifically `11110000 11110000 11110000` to the Arduino.  Why is this happening?

Here is my code that I use to set the `DCB`:

```
HANDLE m_hComm = CreateFile("COM4", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
m_dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(m_dcb);
m_dcb.BaudRate = CBR_115200;
m_dcb.ByteSize = 8;
m_dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
m_dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
SetCommState(m_hComm, &m_dcb);
```

The documentation for `SetCommState` can be found on [Microsoft's website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcommstate):

Comment: It's definitely three `0xF0`'s, but why... Can you show the complete program? Where you _just_ do the opening and `SetCommState` part with nothing else?

Comment: I have added the HANDLE to show more of the code.  That is all that is needed to make a COM port connection.

Comment: I've made a few programs communicating over the `COM` ports myself. None was that short. Can you make a program that compiles as-is and gives the unwanted result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that this happens when `baudRate` is abobe ~50,000.  I found some other people who have had this issue, and there is no answer for them.  One suggested it could be a start byte sent or received at a different baud rate.

Regardless, I fixed it by setting the baud rate to below 50,000.